# Why isn't this style applying to the target element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply `padding: 100px` to some elements targeted via `nth-child` but it only works when I apply it directly to the `work-layer` class. Why?

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 padding: 25px;
}

.nav-item {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.logo {
 width: 50px;
 height: 85px;
 padding-right: 150px;
}

.landing {
 background-image: url('img/bg.png');
 height: 800px;
 margin-top: -150px;
}

.who-am-i {
 color: white;
 font-size: 3.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-top: 25px;
}

.cursor {
 background: white;
 width: 7px;
 height: 75px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 animation: blink .8s steps(5, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
 to { visibility: hidden; }
}

.layer {
 display: flex;
 -ms-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 height:100%;
 color: white;
}

.my-work-heading {
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 background: #000;
 padding: 15px;
}
.work {
 width: 100%;
}

.work-layer {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 color: white;
 height: 100%;
 padding-left: 100px;
}

.work:nth-child(odd) { 
 text-align: right;
}

.work:nth-child(even) {
}

.name { 
 font-size: 3em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.desc {
 font-size: 1.75em;
 width: 40%;
}

.url {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: white;
}

.work-layer { height: 300px; }

.layer-textastic { background-color: rgba(0,133,255,1); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Jordan Baron</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="nav">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
  <a href="#" class="nav-item">My Work</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-item">Projects</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="landing">
  <div class="layer">
   <div class="who-am-i"></div>
   <div class="cursor"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="my-work-heading">
  <h1>My Work</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="work">
  <div class="work-container textastic">
   <div class="work-layer layer-textastic">
    <h1 class="name">Textastic</h1>
    <p class="desc">I made this website as an homage to a great little text editor for iOS known as Textastic</p>
    <a href="#" class="url">jordanbaron.me/Updated-Textastic-Site</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="type.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which children of `.work` do you want the `padding-left` applied to? Just `.work-container`? Or do you want it individually on each of the `<h1>`, `<p>` and `<a`> tags?

Comment: `.work-container`

Answer (score 0):

I think where you are going wrong is thinking that `.work:nth-child()` will affect the **children** of `.work`. Perhaps a bit confusingly, `nth-child` affects the nth **occurences** of the selector.

That is to say, `.work:nth-child(even)` will select the 2nd, 4th and 6th `.work` class:

```css
.work:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="work">One</div>
<div class="work">Two</div>
<div class="work">Three</div>
<div class="work">Four</div>
<div class="work">Five</div>
<div class="work">Six</div>
```

If you want to target direct children, you can make use of the **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** to target any elements that are exactly one level under work, with `.work > *`.

However, considering you only have one `.work-container`, you'd be far better off referencing `.work-container` directly.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I want to target the 1st,3rd, and so on occurrences of `.work` I only have one now but later on I want to add more.

Answer (score 0):

You only have ONE `.work` element, so  `nth-child` rules won't have much impact.

However, if you want to address the children elements of `.work`, you can use (for example) this selector: `.work > *:nth-child(odd) { ... }`. This will select all odd-numbered child elements of `.work`, regardless of their type.